# É possível aplicar efeito de sombra externo e interno em uma box no css3?

Tags: css3

Por exemplo, quero adicionar a um botão de menu um efeito de sombra interno e externo, é possível?
Apliquei uma vez mas um removia o outro!

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é só usar vírgula:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000, inset 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```